# Scroll View does not work on OS 4.1.2

Tags: java, android, android-scrollview

I have added scroll view in a layout, scroll view has attributes of match parent for height and width also fillViewPort is true for scroll view, its working in other devices but not working in android OS 4.1.2.

[image]

Layout :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!--    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    &lt;!&ndash;    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:alpha="0.5"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/page"/>&ndash;&gt;
    </RelativeLayout>-->

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="8">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/main_welcome"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
        android:text="@string/welcome"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridviewMain"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_40dp"
        android:columnWidth="80dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"></GridView>

</LinearLayout>


    </ScrollView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView20"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="false"
        android:text="For Any Queries Related To Mobile App Click On Service Request"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

What can be the reason for this? All other scroll views are working in same device just not working on this screen.

Please help.Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

Try Using nestedScrollView instead

```
<nestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="8">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/main_welcome"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
        android:text="@string/welcome"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridviewMain"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_40dp"
        android:columnWidth="80dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"></GridView>

</LinearLayout>


    </nestedScrollView>
```

Comment: I tried to add nested view, its giving binary inflate exception.